# RSpec attr_readonly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, readonly

I have a product that has a readonly attribute called `rfid`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :rfid
```

I have the following spec to check that it is, indeed, readonly

```
describe Product do
  before :each do
    @product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
  end
  it "'s rfid is immutable'" do
    @product.update_attribute(:rfid, 1921)
    @product.valid?
    expect(@product.errors[:rfid]).to include("marked as readonly")
  end
```

But it fails and returns:

```
  1) Product 's rfid is immutable'
     Failure/Error: @product.update_attribute(:rfid, 1921)
     ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError:
       rfid is marked as readonly
```

I tried with
`"has already been taken"`
and `expect(@product.rfid).to eq(1921)` and `to have(1).errors` etc. to no avail

As usual, any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to update a read only attribute will raise an `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError` erorr, rather than add a validation error to the model.  You can test that the error is raised with:

```
expect {
  @product.update_attribute(:rfid, 1921)
}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError, 'rfid is marked as readonly')
```

Comment: To the model or to the object? @infused

Comment: I dont understand where the validation errors get sent. BTW typo in your answer @infused

Comment: attr_reader does not create a validation error.  It simply raises an `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError` error.